# Iteration appears to have been ignored?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

**Information:**

I have a list of "Properties" to iterate over, and it seems to ignore iteration (though the iteration works). Honestly I'm not sure what is happening. I've walked through the debugger step by step and it's just mysteriously not working.

**My Razor View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    for (Int32 I = 0; I < this.ViewData.Model.Properties.Count; ++I)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Properties._Properties[I], "Property")
    }
}
```

**Property EditorTemplate**

```
@model NMBS.EntityModels.Property

@Html.HiddenFor(p => p.ID)
@Html.LabelFor(p => p.Name)
@Html.HiddenFor(p => p.DataType)
@Html.HiddenFor(p => p.ValueFormat)
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Value.Value)
@Html.HiddenFor(p => p.Value.DataType)
@Html.HiddenFor(p => p.Value.ValueFormat)
<br />
```

**Problem:**

The output is as expected except for the values in the controls. They're all the value from m.Properties[0], as I step through the for-loop I check the value of I and it is increasing. m.Properties[0] and m.Properties[1] are different (verified while debugging).

Just to clarify: The EditorFor creates the correct controls but the values are all from m.Properties[0] instead of m.Properties[I]. I does increase with each iteration of the loop though. If I replace the for-loop with `@Html.EditorFor(e => e.Properties._Properties)` it does the same thing.

**Question:** Any Ideas why it's outputting incorrect values even though it is iterating correctly?

**Edit:**
After further examination I've noticed that it's trying to put the correct values in the TextBoxFor Value.Value, however the LabelFor Name is incorrect and always showing "Name".

Comment: *however the LabelFor Name is incorrect and always showing "Name".* what would you expect it to show?

Comment: The Property's Name. m.Properties[0]'s Name is "Name" but m.Proeprties[1]'s Name is "Description". Sorry for that.

Comment: `LabelFor` writes out the name of the property, not the value of it. The property name is `Name` in all instances because... the property is called `Name`. Unless `Properties` is a list of different classes with different display names specified in the model metadata, in which case you need to add this code to your question. If you want the value of the property instead of the name, perhaps you wanted to use `DisplayFor` instead of `LabelFor`.

Comment: Well, I feel retarded. Okay, write that as an answer so I can mark it, I'm sure that's the issue (Definitely was the issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is that `LabelFor` doesn't write out the value of the property, it writes out a label associated with it. By default, this is simply the property name, but can be overriden using the `DisplayAttribute` or `DisplayNameAttribute` on your model property.

In your example above, this will always result in the same value being written out, because it's the same model property in every iteration.

If you want to write out the *value* of the property, use `DisplayFor`:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Name)
```

Or, simply:

```
@Model.Name
```